# On Haar measure and Spherical measure

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, haar-measure

Let $d$-dimensional complex sphere be

$$\{(c_1,\cdots,c_{d})\sum_{i=1}^{d} |c_i|^2=1.\}$$

We can define the Haar measure on this sphere by regarding the unitary group $U(d)$.

We can regard the $d$-dimensional complex sphere as the $2d$-dimensional real sphere and consider the sphere measure as the uniform distribution on the sphere.

Are these two measures identical?

What about the relationship between the Fubini-study metric and the sphere measure?

Comment: The use of terminology seems either imprecise or unconventional. A (left) Haar measure is a measure on a **group** which is invariant under (left) translation. So there is no "Haar measure" on the d-dimensional complex sphere. Could you also please clarify what you mean by the d-dimensional complex sphere: do you mean the set of norm-one vectors in ${\bf C}^d$? If so, then the unitary group which acts on this is $U(d)$, not $U(d+1)$.

Comment: What is true is that the set of norm-one vectors in the complex inner product space ${\bf C}^d$ can be identified with the set $S^{2d-1}$ of norm-one vectors in the real inner product space ${\bf R}^{2d}$. When we make this identification, it defines an injective group homomorphism $U(d) \to O(2d)$. If we denote the range of this embedding by $G$, then maybe the intended question is: *is uniform measure on $S^{2d-1}$ the only $G$-invariant probability measure?

Comment: Thank you and that is exactly the question I want to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, (of course, up to scalar multiples), the $U(n)$-invariant measure on $S^{2n-1}$ must be the same as the $O(2n)$-invariant measure on $S^{2n-1}$... for example, because the $U(n)$-invariant measure is *also* $O(2n)$-invariant, and there is a unique such measure...

Comment: Thank you! What about the relationship between the Fubini-study metric and the sphere measure?